# Use Jersey to upload XLS file?

Tags: java, rest, upload, jersey, xls

I'm using Jersey to upload files to my application for processing.  I implemented a version for uploading TXT and CSV files which works.  However when I upload an XLS file I get this:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
```

I'm using ApachePOI to read the file but even in the `xls` method if I check how many bytes are available in the stream I get zero.  The file i'm testing with definitely has data in it and is a valid XLS file but I can't understand why it thinks the stream is closed.

My `xls` method is as follows:

```
    @POST
    @NewUpload
    @Path(FILE_PATH)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @AccessLog
    public Response xls(
            @QueryParam(USER_PARAM)    final String userID,
            @FormDataParam(FILE_PARAM) final InputStream upload,
            @FormDataParam(FILE_PARAM) final FormDataContentDisposition detail,
            @FormDataParam(TYPE_PARAM) final String type)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Available bytes " + upload.available());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }
        return upload(userID, upload, detail, type);
    } //xls
```

The methods for TXT and CSV are exactly the same except set to a different address and the method `upload(userID, upload, detail, type)` deals with the different streams appropraitely.

Is there a way to reset the stream so that I can read it properly after this point?  Or is there a different way of reading XLS files?

Also for huge files is it better to do this another way i.e. save the file to disk from the upload then to read it in?

Thanks in advance,
Alexei Blue.

EDIT 1:
I added a call to IOUtils to read some of the Stream in the `xls` method and managed to read a lot of bytes so I guess the Stream is being closed by something else.

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[10000];
try {
    System.out.println("Bytes read " + IOUtils.read(upload, buffer));
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
}
```

I'll try creating a unit test to simulate what's happening so I can see where the stream is being closed.

EDIT 2:
The client is written as a front-end web application, written in cold fusion:

```
<cfoutput>
    <legend>Upload File</legend>

    <div id ="uploadfile">
        <form class = "form-horizontal" id="upload_file_form" method="post" name="upload_file">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">File To Upload</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="filetoupload" class="filetoupload" type="file" name="file">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="button" 
                       value="Submit" 
                       name="submit" 
                       class="btn btn-success" 
                       id="submit" 
                       onclick="doUpload(upload_file_form);" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

The `doUpload` script:

```
function doUpload(form) {
    var id = $('[name="id"]').val();
    var fileExtension = getFileExtension(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(form),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: "/application/rest/upload/" + fileExtension + "/file/?id=" + id,
        success:function(data) {
             // get the upload id
             var uploadID = data;
             window.location ="index.cfm?controller=project&action=status&id=" + id + "&uploadID='" + uploadID + "'";
        }
    });
}
```

Currently I'm running the upload in a component test which made me realise the header of the file is read however the file in the component test is of the type `BufferedInputStream` but the stream when running the code from the client is `org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream` so it could be a problem with the mimepull dependancy, any thoughts?

Cheers, 
Alexei Blue.

Edit 3: I think I found the problem.  In my upload method I was spinning the process off in another thread to ensure the request wasn't waiting around.  Jersey must close the stream on returning from the method and with CSV and TXT being very simple file types they must have processed in the thread before the starting thread returned.  I'll need to confirm this tomorrow as I'm out of time today but I'll be sure to post the results.  The upload method was as follows:

```
protected Response upload(
            final String id, 
            final InputStream input,
            final FormDataContentDisposition detail, 
            final String type) 
    {
        String id = UUIDs.timeBased().toString();

        factory
            .set(id, uploadID)
            .setFilename(detail.getFileName())
            .setType(type);

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
               upload.process(input); 
            } //run
        }).start();

        return Response.ok(uploadID).build();
    } //upload
```

Comment: Could you add the client part from where you are uploading the file?

Comment: Hi @tmarwen see Edit 2 for front end client and some more details.  I'm going to try and find the code for DataHead in the mimepull library to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Jersey was closing the stream so I can't just spin up a new thread to put the processing part into the background.  This isn't a problem as the status of the upload can be obtained by polling the status URL so the user can still get a response in the interface with AJax.

The new upload method, i.e. with out the thread.

```
protected Response upload(
            final String id, 
            final InputStream input,
            final FormDataContentDisposition detail, 
            final String type) 
    {
        String id = UUIDs.timeBased().toString();

        factory
            .set(id, uploadID)
            .setFilename(detail.getFileName())
            .setType(type);

        upload.process(input);

        return Response.ok(uploadID).build();
    } //upload
```